# android studio 4.0.1 elements * must be declared

Tags: android, android-studio

i am running android studio 4.0.1 as a new beginner  
the problem is:  
i just created a new project (empty activity) named "hello world" -as always- and tried to run it without any edit.  
when pressing run i had the error "Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag"
while rereading the script in file "app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml", it is seems to be the "manifest" element is not declared.  
and i had noticed that there are other files has the same problem -undeclared element - like:

- res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml(v24) ....  "element vector must be declared"
- res/layout/activitymain.xml .... "element androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout must be declared"
- res/mipmap/ic_luncher/ic_luncher.xml(anydpi-v26) .... "element adaptive-icon must be declared"
- res/mipmap/ic_luncher_round/ic_luncher_round.xml(anydpi-v26) .... "element adaptive-icon must be declared"
- res/values/colors.xml .... "element resources must be declared"
- res/values/strings.xml .... "element resources must be declared"
- res/values/styles.xml .... "element resources must be declared"  

  what i should do to fix those errors and make my app run correctly?  
  best regards.

Comment: try this :- File->Invalidate Caches / Restard and choose invaliadate and restart

Comment: app dev .. i tried that many times beside "sync gradle" and "rebuild"

Comment: close project delete .gradle and .idea file and again open it

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon it didn't work either.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you fixed it?